# Is there a good reason to use a public property / field?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic

One of the important parts of object-oriented programming is encapsulation, but public properties / fields tend to break this encapsulation. Under what circumstances does a public property or field actually make sense?

*Note: I only use the term 'property' or 'field' because terminology varies between languages. In general, I mean a variable that belongs to an object that can be accessed and set from outside the object.*

Comment: Have a look at this: [Properties vs. Public Variables](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/properties-vs-public-variables.html). I think the same behavior can be achieve in other language than .NET, like ruby.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, there are sometimes good reasons.** Information hiding is usually desirable. But there are some occasional exceptions.

For example, public fields are reasonable and useful for:

- A C++ pimpl - a struct/class holding the private implementation of another class. Its fields may be declared public syntatically, but are typically accessible only within one source file, by the class holding the pimpl.
- Constant fields. For example, Joshua Bloch writes in *Effective Java*: "Classes are permitted to expose constants via public static final fields."
- Structs used for communication between C and C++.
- Types which represent only data, whose representation is unlikely to change. For example, javax.vecmath.Point3d, which represents an {x,y,z} coordinate.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: never.

Actually, if you use an object for simply storing data, but the object itself does no logic, and you never mean to derive from this object, then it is OK to have public fields. Sometimes I do things like this in C++:

```
struct A {
    int a;
    float b;
    string c;
    A():a(0),b(0.0) {}
    A(int a_, float b_, string c_):a(a_),b(b_),c(c_) {}
};
```

But other than having initializing constructors, it is nothing more than a C struct. If your class does anything more than this, than you should never use public (or even protected) fields.

As for properties, it depends on what language you use. For example, in Delphi, the main purpose of properties is to provide public interfaces to fields, and can provide getters/setters to them, while still working syntactically like a variable.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a good reason to use a public
>   property / field?

**No.**

Public members are always dangerous. You may not need any control now, but once you expose them, you lose any possibility of having control later. If you have gettes/setters right away you have room for adding control later.

<sub>Ps:
Depending on the language you use, properties and fields may mean different things.
[C# properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) are actually a way to both achieve encapsulation and at the same time not being very verbose.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There is a bad reason:  by directly accessing the datum you avoid pushing a method call onto the stack, for what that's worth.

In many languages this is also achievable by inlining the accessor method/s.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of the object is to hold data in its fields, then yes. It would also make sense to have methods on the object which are (a) purely functional (in that they do not change the state of the object, or anything else); or (b) which manipulate the state of the object, and the point is that they manipulate the state in a particular way.

The kind of things that you should avoid are (c) methods that do things to other objects based on the state of the object (and certainly if there are assumptions about what is a "valid" state).